# Adding exclusions to multi word synonyms in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

I have the following synonyms (just for this example)

```
"synonyms": {
"type": "synonym_graph",
"expand": true,
"lenient": true,
"tokenizer": "standard",
"synonyms": [
    "french => french, ethnicity",
    "toast => toast, cheese sandwich"
]}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is as follows:

If a user is searching for "french" I wish him to receive all the documents that contain "french" and/or "ethnicity".

But If a user searches for "french toast" I want him to only receive documents that contain "french toast" without "ethnicity toast".

Using the _analyze api

```
GET test-xxx/_analyze
{
  "text": "french toast" ,
  "analyzer": "synonyms"
}
```

I'm getting the following

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "french",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "ethnic",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "toast",
      "start_offset" : 7,
      "end_offset" : 12,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 1,
      "positionLength" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "chees",
      "start_offset" : 7,
      "end_offset" : 12,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "sandwich",
      "start_offset" : 7,
      "end_offset" : 12,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 2
    }
  ]
}
```

If I'm adding "french toast" as a single explicit synonym it seems to ignore 'french' and 'toast' synonyms

```
"synonyms": {
    "type": "synonym_graph",
    "expand": true,
    "lenient": true,
    "tokenizer": "standard",
    "synonyms": [
        "french toast => french toast",
        "french => french, ethnicity",
        "toast => toast, cheese sandwich"
    ]}
```

Leads to

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "french",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 12,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "toast",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 12,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

But still it returns documents that contain "french" and/or "toast" while I with to receive only the ones with "french toast".

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The tokenizer you have used is [standard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html).

> The standard tokenizer provides grammar based tokenization

it will split "french toast are delicious" in ["french" ,"toast","are", "delicious"]

If you are searching for "french toast" in above text
You can pass operator as "AND" in match query or you match_phrase

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "text": "french toast" --> phrase should match
    }
  }
}


{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": {
        "query": "french toast",
        "operator": "and" --> both tokens must be present
      }
    }
  }
}
```